# How to generate Fibonacci sequence from first and second values?

Tags: java, fibonacci

How to recursively generate Fibonacci sequence from first and second values? For `fib(int f0, int f1, int n)` where `f0` is first value of sequence and `f1` the second, what should the code look like?

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
public static int fib(int f0, int f1, int n)
{
if (n == f0){
        return f0;
    }
if (n == f1){
        return f1;
    }
return fib(f0, f1, n-1) + fib(f0, f1, n-2);
}
```

Comment: [LGTM (`ideone.com`)](https://ideone.com/5TmHX1). What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You could not know, but some of us here regard "it doesn’t work" as a favourite aversion because it’s often impossible to answer a question when we don’t know more than that. In your case too, I am afraid. Therefore, please paste into your question any error message or any wrong results that you have observed from the code you have posted. In addition also enter the results that you had expected and would have considered correct. So that we can understand the problem you are asking about. So we have a chance to help you. Thanks.

Comment: Comparing `n` to `f0` and `f1` seems wrong. Shouldn’t you compare to 1 and 2 instead? (Or to 0 and 1 depending on how you count the values.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way.  Just supply the first and second value and the number of terms to print.

```
fib(0,1, 12);
    
public static void fib(int first, int second, int nTerms) {
    System.out.println(first);
    if(nTerms == 0) {
        return;
    }
    fib(second, first+second, --nTerms);
}
```

prints

```
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
144
```

Comment: Omg it works! I should figure more about it. Thank you so much.